# Publish fails at deployment phase

Tags: deployer, publishingfailed, web8, web8.5

I am getting errors while publishing at deploying phase. I am using SDL WEB 8.5 with upgraded 2011 database. I am publishing using the legacy publishing feature where I have added the Discovery Services with deployer capability.

While publishing the Zip file is being transferred and unzipped to the targeted folder. After that I am getting error.

**Deployer_conf.xml**::

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Deployer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="8.5" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/deployer-conf.xsd">
        <Pipelines>
            <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Bootstrap" Action="TridionBootstrap" Verb="Content,Prepare,Commit">
                <Steps>
                    <Step Id="TridionUnzipStep"/>
                </Steps>
            </Pipeline>
            <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Wait" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Wait">
                <Steps>
                    <Step Id="TridionWaitStep"/>
                </Steps>
            </Pipeline>
            <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Process-Deploy" Action="Deploy" Verb="Process">
                <Steps>
                    <Step Id="SchemaDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy" Type="SchemaDeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="PageDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy" Type="PageDeploy">
                            <Transformer Class="com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer"/>
                        </Module>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="BinaryDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy" Type="BinaryDeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="ComponentDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy" Type="ComponentDeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="TemplateDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy" Type="TemplateDeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="PublicationDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy" Type="PublicationDeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="TaxonomyDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy" Type="TaxonomyDeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="ComponentPresentationDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy" Type="ComponentPresentationDeploy">
                            <Transformer Class="com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer"/>
                        </Module>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="StructureGroupDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy" Type="StructureGroupDeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                </Steps>
            </Pipeline>
            <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Process-Undeploy" Action="Undeploy" Verb="Process">
                <Steps>
                    <Step Id="PageUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageUndeploy" Type="PageUndeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="ComponentPresentationUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationUndeploy" Type="ComponentPresentationUndeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="TaxonomyUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyUndeploy" Type="TaxonomyUndeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                    <Step Id="StructureGroupUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                        <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupUndeploy" Type="StructureGroupUndeploy"/>
                    </Step>
                </Steps>
            </Pipeline>
            <Pipeline Id="Tridion-PreCommit-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="PreCommit">
                <Steps>
                    <Step Id="TridionPreCommitStep"/>
                </Steps>
            </Pipeline>
            <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Commit-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Commit">
                <Steps>
                    <Step Id="TridionCommitStep">
                        <RetryPoint PipelineId="Tridion-PreCommit-TX" StepId="TridionPreCommitStep"/>
                    </Step>
                </Steps>
            </Pipeline>
            <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Rollback-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Rollback">
                <Steps>
                    <Step Id="TridionRollbackStep"/>
                </Steps>
            </Pipeline>
            <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Cleanup" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="*">
                <Steps>
                    <Step Id="TridionCleanupStep"/>
                </Steps>
            </Pipeline>
        </Pipelines>

        <!-- Binary Storage configuration -->
        <BinaryStorage Id="PackageStorage" Adapter="FileSystem">
            <Property Name="Path" Value="C:/SDLWeb/Binary"/>
        </BinaryStorage>

        <State>
            <Storage Adapter="mssql" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver">
                <Property Name="host" Value="wordpressdev"/>
                <Property Name="port" Value="1433"/>
                <Property Name="database" Value="Tridion_Broker_Old"/>
                <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser"/>
                <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion!232!"/>
            </Storage>
        </State>

        <!-- Queues configuration -->
        <Queues>
            <!-- Queues default configuration for Filesystem-->
            <Queue Default="true" Verbs="Content" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="ContentQueue">
                <Property Name="Destination" Value="C:/SDLWeb/Queue"/>
                <!-- Optional property to set number of workers
                <Property Name="Workers" Value="11"/> -->
            </Queue>
            <Queue Verbs="Commit,Rollback" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="CommitQueue">
                <Property Name="Destination" Value="C:/SDLWeb/Queue/FinalTX"/>
                <!-- Optional property to set number of workers
                <Property Name="Workers" Value="11"/> -->
            </Queue>
            <Queue Verbs="Prepare" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="PrepareQueue">
                <Property Name="Destination" Value="C:/SDLWeb/Queue/Prepare"/>
                <!-- Optional property to set number of workers
                <Property Name="Workers" Value="11"/> -->
            </Queue>
            <Adapter Id="FileSystem">
                <!-- optional property to set polling interval
                <Property Name="LocationPollingInterval" Value="2s"/> -->
            </Adapter>
            <!-- Workers configuration properties -->
            <Workers>
                <!-- Optional configuration properties
                <Property Name="QueuePollingInterval" Value="2s"/>
                <Property Name="RetriesInterval" Value="100ms"/>
                <Property Name="MaxRetries" Value="11"/>
                <Property Name="Cleanup" Value="true"/> -->
            </Workers>
        </Queues>
        <!-- License Path -->
         <License Path="D:\Websites\SDL_MicroServices\staging\cd_licenses.xml" />
    </Deployer>
```

Please find the logs here:

```
    2017-06-08 16:40:58,033 ERROR StepActor - Step 'SchemaDeploy' for 'tcm:0-229389-66560' can NOT retry
    2017-06-08 16:40:58,037 ERROR StepActor - Step 'SchemaDeploy' for 'tcm:0-229389-66560': 
    com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Could not deploy schema com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.Schema@8dbe5ae1
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.process(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:101)
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$execute(StepActor.scala:60)
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:44)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:27)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
    Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Unable to determine namespace id
        at com.tridion.storage.namespace.NamespaceLoader.getInstance(NamespaceLoader.java:93)
        at com.tridion.storage.deploy.SchemaHandler.deploy(SchemaHandler.java:58)
        at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:101)
        at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:55)
        at com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy.processSchema(SchemaDeploy.java:198)
        at com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy.processItem(SchemaDeploy.java:182)
        at com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy.processSection(SchemaDeploy.java:93)
        at com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy.process(SchemaDeploy.java:78)
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.process(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:91)
        ... 13 common frames omitted
    Caused by: com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Not possible to parse the XML configuration in 'org.xml.sax.InputSource@6076d256'
        at com.sdl.delivery.configuration.xml.XMLConfigurationReaderImpl.getXmlNode(XMLConfigurationReaderImpl.java:137)
        at com.sdl.delivery.configuration.xml.XMLConfigurationReaderImpl.readConfiguration(XMLConfigurationReaderImpl.java:76)
        at com.tridion.storage.namespace.NamespaceLoader.getInstance(NamespaceLoader.java:51)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sdl.delivery.configuration.xml.XMLConfigurationReaderImpl.getXmlNode(XMLConfigurationReaderImpl.java:134)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
    2017-06-08 16:40:58,076 ERROR CommandQueuePoller - Could not process command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-229389-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-229389-66560', properties={}} reason: Could not deploy schema com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.Schema@8dbe5ae1
```

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When looking at the stacktrace, the bottom of the stacktrace contains this message

```
 Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Basically, this means that there is an error somewhere in one of your configuration files.
I'm guessing that somewhere you have a nested xml comment, which is not permitted

eg :

```
 <!-- commented xml 
    <!-- some other comment -->

 end of commented xml
 -->
```

so, check your configuration files, and remove any "--" string within commented xml.